# How to get newly changed value after apply React useState in a handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is a React code chunk:

```js
const [win, setWin] => useState(false)
const [guessedNumber, setGuessedNumber] => useState(undefined)

const clickHandler = () => {
   setGuessedNumber(randomNumber())

   if(guessedNumber === 10) {
     setWin(true)
   }
}
```

Explanation: after clicking on button (not presented here) the handler `clickHandler` fires. Generates random number, `setGuessedNumber` hook runs. But due to batching the new
value of `guessedNumber` we can find after `clickHandler` do it works. But I need to see the new value of `guessedNumber` immediately.

Here is my solution I have done:

```
const [win, setWin] => useState(false)
const [guessedNumber, setGuessedNumber] => useState(undefined)

const clickHandler = () => {
   const rndNum = randomNumber()

   setGuessedNumber(rndNum)

   if(rndNum === 10) {
     setWin(true)
   }
}
```

The `setGuessedNumber` I use for rerender, `rndNum` for the calculations and logics.

Is it right solution? Or there is something React'ish?

Comment: Instead of having two separate states you could use a "computed state". eg. change `const [win, setWin] => useState(false)` into `const win = guessedNumber === 10`. In this scenario `setGuessedNumber(randomNumber())` would update both states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done in the second example is correct.

```
const [win, setWin] => useState(false)
const [guessedNumber, setGuessedNumber] => useState(undefined)

const clickHandler = () => {
   const rndNum = randomNumber()

   setGuessedNumber(rndNum)

   if(rndNum === 10) {
     setWin(true)
   }
}
```

These hooks are asynchronous. They just queue the updates rather than immediately executing them. You can refer this. https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately

Comment: At the moment I guess it's the simplest solution that works well.

Comment: @GregoryKafanov actually I think that Matriarx's answer is the simplest solution that works best.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're storing state for win when you already know that you're winning at "10", seems like that logic should be somewhere else which is why you're racking your brain with these workarounds.

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState()

...

return <>
  ...
  {number === 10 && <div>You're winning!</div>}
</>
```

Comment: Its just an example for common problem. Not for specific task to show  'You're winning!'

Comment: Yes just an example, you can put anything in your return.  The example is just to show where you can test that logic ````number === 10```` and how you can conditionally render components from it.  That logic doesn't need an entire additional state just for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid and correct. React will queue state change requests and apply them at the right time after calculating the minimum DOM modification.

Actually, in your case it seems to be the best solution. The only alternative that comes to my mind is to use `useEffect` hook as follows:

```js
const [win, setWin] = useState(false);
const [guessedNumber, setGuessedNumber] = useState(undefined);

const clickHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setGuessedNumber(randomNumber());
}, [randomNumber]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (guessedNumber === 10) {
        setWin(true);
    }
}, [guessedNumber]);
```

The `useEffect` callback will execute each time `guessedNumber` changes and the component re-renders.

As I mentioned before, in your case I think that your solution will be more efficient as only one re-render will be triggered!